# uitableviewcell setSelectedBackgroundView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

i have app with splitviewcontroller , in master view of splitview i have uitableview and in detail view i have image gallery .which shows large image of the item selected in cell of uitable view of master view.

i also have previous next button in image gallery so that user can go to previous or next photo ie in detail view of split view.

**now i want to set selected to cell of tableview in master view of splitview when user tap next or previous in detail view.**

i must be able to setSelectedBackgroundView of uitablecell in master view from detail view in splitview

any help or tutorial or link or idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you already have a valid reference to the master view from the detail view? Or do you need to set up a way for them to communicate?

Comment: i need to set up the way to communicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would connect the Back/Next buttons to the same view controller that supplies data to the UITableView. The actions for back and next would then simply need to use `-indexPathForSelectedRow` to find the currently selected cell and then `-selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` to make your UITableView select the new one.

Just to be clear:

Your UIViewController (your custom subclass) would have:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; // An IBOutlet to the table
- (IBAction)next; // tells the tableView to select the next cell
- (IBAction)previous; // tells the tableView to select the previous cell
```

Comment: yes bro , done it thanks a lot.i didn't do the way you told because i have different scenario , but i got your idea and it worked ,thanks a lot, really appreciate that.